# Activate at least one of the options in PHP

Tags: php

I want at least one option with more than options to be selectable. How do I make all other options inaccessible.

For example:

```
<select id="" name="">
  <option value="">Option 1</option>
  <option value="" disabled>Option 2</option>
  <option value="" disabled>Option 3</option>
  <option value="" disabled>Option 4</option>
  <option value="" disabled>Option 5</option>
  <option value="" disabled>Option 6</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {                                              
  $hugeArray = json_decode($option->content, true);                                                              
     foreach ($hugeArray as $key => $value) {                                                                    
         echo "<option value='" . $value . "'>" . $value . "</option>";                                                              
       }                                                             
   }
```

it doesn't matter which one is selectable. How can I do that?

Comment: you'll need a multi-select list type and basic if else condition to disable one or more options

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi Thank you for your comment. Not multiple choice. Only at least one must be active